# Streaming video without sound iOS9/iPhone6, objective C

Tags: objective-c, iphone, ios9

I have implemented video streaming in my "example" iOS app. But I have a problem with sound. It's not working in real device. Have you guys experienced some similar problem? I am new in iOS developing. Thanks
PS:I can't publish url, so therefore it's "blabla". But of course I used valid URL.

```
- (IBAction)clickedPlay:(id)sender {

    NSURL *liveStreamURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"blabla"];

    _player = [[MPMoviePlayerViewController alloc] initWithContentURL:liveStreamURL];
    [self presentMoviePlayerViewControllerAnimated:_player];


}
```

Comment: Well there could either be something with the audio codec or you device is muted!

Comment: u were right, device was muted. Thanks. i didn't know that could not ignore this hardware button :(